# Sharepoint Context Info in HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I'm building a SPA inside Sharepoint 2013 by uploading javascript and html files to a document library.  I'm trying to get current user info by accessing context info through the sp.js library. But i get this error:

```
_spPageContextInfo is not defined
```

In my index.aspx file i include the following js:

```
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
```

I also included this at the top of the index.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint"
 Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
 Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
```

In my js file i have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // wait for the sharepoint javascript libraries to load, then call the function 'Initialize'
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");   
});
function runCode() {
    var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
}
```

It should be mentioned that i use Angular JS to build the app, and I use Angular UI Router library for navigation between pages.

The document library is inside a subsite in a side collection.

E.g.

intra.xxx.xxx/xxx/index.aspx

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you loading your context?

Comment: The index.aps resides in a document library inside sharepoint (intra.xxx.xxx/index.aspx). On the index.aspx i'm loading all the sp.js files. I using angular ui router for routing purposes.

Comment: Which Sharepoint Version ? Where is the page ? Document LIbrary or file system ?

Comment: Witch line throw error ? Can you post the code, I think you must start the angular app by [manual initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) after load the sp.js library

Comment: Why is the question being down voted? Do I miss something?

Comment: @TietjeDK Please check order of JS files. If code written by you is in init.js you should mention it after other 4 js files. below article will help you in setting right script files for getting _spPageContextInfo object http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116359/bare-minimum-page-to-get-sppagecontextinfo-loaded

Comment: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
                var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
                . . .
        
            },"SP.JS");

Comment: I have follow the guide and tried using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){ var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId; . . . },"SP.JS"); ` With no luck. In the console i can see that all sp scripts get loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I apperantly was missing some sharepoint dependencies on my index.aspx file.

**Solution**

Start of index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Scripts in header:

```
<!--Sharepoint Dependencies-->
    <script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/1033/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.Core.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en%2Dus&name=SP%2ERes"></script>
```

Body:

```
<!-- required: SharePoint FormDigest -->
<form runat="server">
  <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
</form>
```